# WebStorm TSLint: error: unknown option `-t json'

Tags: angular, typescript, webstorm, tslint

My Angular2 project in WebStorm suddenly started to show for each TSLint .ts inspection

[image: WebStorm TSLint error]

```
TSLint: error: unknown option `-t json'
```

Comment: What TSLint version do you have?

Comment: Using version tslint@5.5.0

Comment: I was getting that same error on that same version. It's not really a fix, but I did get that error to go away by reverting back to an older version (specifically codelyzer@2.1.1 and tslint@2.4.1).

Comment: Changed from tslint@5.5 back to tslint@4.5.1 fixed it for me, thank you!

Comment: Fixed issue for me also. Downgrated tslint@5.6 back to tslint@4.5.1.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I just reverted back from tslint@5.5 to tslint@4.5.1 and tslint started working again with WebStorm.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade Webstorm to version 2017.2.4